# How to render a partial without data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial `div` in my application working well.

The usually:

in controller action:

```
@order = Order.where(service: params[:id], table: session[:table_id]).first
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

in action.js.erb:

```
$('#order').html("<%= escape_javascript render(@order) %>");
```

in view:

```
<div id="order">
  <%= render @order unless @order.nil? %>
```

But when `@order` is `nil` I want to render a partial blank. As usual, when is `nil` I get the error: `ActionView::Template::Error ('nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.):`

Summarizing, when `@order` is `nil` I want to refresh the partial with a blank "div". What is the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#order').html("<%= escape_javascript @order ? render(@order) : '' %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Only render it if it is not nil

```
<div id="order">
  <%= render @order unless @order.nil? %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @brennan. I tried, but is not the solution. Even if I only render if it is not `nil`, in the controller, the `format.js` throws the `action.js.erb` with the resulting `ActionView::Template::Error`

Comment: Sorry, I did't read thoroughly. You should have the same in your JS template

Comment: Sorry @brennan, but if I have the same in the JS template the partial `div` will not change to a blank, I will have the previous partial order...